# Docker on RHEL 8 creating files and folder with 027 permission

Tags: docker, unix, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers

I am running `nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged:stable-alpine` docker image on RHEL 8.8 server. when docker container starts its creating directory and file with umask `0027`.

But my docker  `20.10.17` daemon running with Umask of `0022`. my server default umask is `0027` this I can't change due to security requirements.

```
# systemd-analyze dump |egrep -i 'docker|umask'
 ReferencedBy: docker.service (destination-file)
        UMask: 0022
```

Here is inside container file system permission on **RHEL 8** server.

```
 # ls -l
total 76
drwxr-x---    1 root     root          4096 Jun 16 21:57 app
drwxr-x---    1 root     root          4096 Jun 16 21:57 bin
drwxr-x---    5 root     root           360 Jun 17 20:18 dev
drwxr-x---    1 root     root          4096 Jun 16 21:57 docker-entrypoint.d
-rwxr-x---    1 root     root          1202 Jun 16 21:57 docker-entrypoint.sh
drwxr-x---    1 root     root          4096 Jun 17 20:18 etc
drwxr-x---    2 root     root          4096 Jun 16 21:57 home
drwxrwxrwt    1 root     root          4096 Jun 16 21:57 tmp
drwxr-x---    1 root     root          4096 Jun 16 21:57 usr
drwxr-x---    1 root     root          4096 Jun 16 21:57 var
```

Here is inside container file system permission on **windows machine** with same docker iamge.

```
ls -l 
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 May 23 16:51 bin
drwxr-xr-x    5 root     root           360 Jun 17 18:39 dev
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Jun 16 10:36 docker-entrypoint.d
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          1202 Jun 16 10:36 docker-entrypoint.sh
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Jun 17 18:39 etc
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 May 23 16:51 home 
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 May 23 16:51 usr
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 May 23 16:51 var
```

How can I make docker container file system created with umask of `0022`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> when docker container starts

That means you need to build your own image, based on `nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged:stable-alpine`, with a [new entry point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69233923/6309) like:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
# entrypoint.sh
umask 022
# ... other first-time setup ...
exec "$@"
```

See "[Change umask in docker containers](https://widerin.net/blog/change-umask-in-docker-containers/)" for more details, but the idea remains the same.

Comment: after starting container umask shows `0022`. this permission getting changed while creation of the container. I think some setting need to changed on the host OS configuration.